# How to create a set containing different types

Tags: rascal

How can I create a set containing a loc, int and string?
In the example below it seems my map is converted to the container type ' value'. I would like to use the characteristics of a set;
Only one element should be contained in the set and the order does not matter .
In the example below the same elements are contained in what I was hoping to be a set.

```js
rascal>mySet = ();
map[void, void]: ()
rascal>mySet += {<|project://Test/|, 1, "test"> };
value: {
  (),
  <|project://Test|,1,"test">
}
rascal>mySet += {<|project://Test/|, 1, "test"> };
value: {
  <|project://Test|,1,"test">,
  {
    (),
    <|project://Test|,1,"test">
  }
}
```

Thank you again for advise :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something weird is going on . First mySet is a map, and then you add a set to it and the variable `mySet` is suddenly a set that contains the previous map and the new element you added. It looks to me that `+=` has a bug.

If you want to add several elements to a set, you should start with a set and add elements to it like so:

```
rascal>mySet = { |project://Test| ,1, "test" }; // simply create the set with 3 different elements in it
set[value]: { |project://Test| ,1, "test" }
```

Or you could start with an empty set and add elements:

```
rascal>mySet = {};
set[void]: {}
rascal>mySet += 1;
set[int]: {1}
rascal>mySet += |project://Test|;
set[value]: {1, |project://Test|}
rascal>mySet += "test";
set[value]: {1, |project://Test|, "test"}
```

Comment: Thank you again for your help. 
Is it still possible to bind a name to a type (sorry for probably not using the correct terminology)?

I would like to use a set like this;

set[loc locOfFile, nr , str myText] mySet; 

So I can use the contents of the set later, like:
mySet.locOfFile;

Comment: made a typo;

Can I bind types like this;
set[loc locOfFile, int nr, str myText] mySet;

Comment: Yes but then it's a set of tuples, written in short hand like this:`rel[int a, int b] myRel = {<1,2>};`. Then myRel.a returns a set of int. And `for (e <- myRel) println(e.a);` loops over all the tuples and prints the first field of each tuple. Hope this helps!

Comment: Very much so! Thank you again!